# Get Pancake Swap's Old Pair PairCreated Event

Tags: javascript, web3js, ether, bsc, pancakeswap

I am trying to read Past Event for Pancake Factory Address. But i dont get response.

```
var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73");

contractInstance.getPastEvents('PairCreated', {
filter: {address: "0xa5dd1b661fc1ea194db427cf12aa3cd715312a84"},  
fromBlock: 0,
toBlock: 'latest'
}, (error, events) => { 
// Should return event
  var obj=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(events));
}
else {
  console.log(error)
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe no CreatePair events from 0xa5dd1b661fc1ea194db427cf12aa3cd715312a84 ?
try this form without filter:

`var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,` "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73");

```
contractInstance.getPastEvents('PairCreated', {
fromBlock: 0,
toBlock: 'latest'
}, (error, events) => { 
// Should return event
  var obj=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(events));
}
else {
  console.log(error)
}})
```

Comment: "Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "upstream request timeout""it throws API time out. I am using HTTP provider. Not websocket.

Comment: You need use archive node for this type of operations. Simple provider not usable for this. Try https://alchemyapi.io/ for ETH or https://moralis.io/ free for BSC

Comment: "Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "upstream request timeout""  it throws API time out. I am using HTTP provider. Not websocket.

Comment: yes using speedy nodes of moralis

Comment: need full code, remove only keys

Comment: const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/a21ad581c5f07d0c74fb0cc6/bsc/mainnet'));

(async ()=>{
    var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73");
    contractInstance.getPastEvents('PairCreated', {
      fromBlock: 0,
      toBlock: 'latest'
      }, (error, events) => { 
      // Should return event
      console.log(error)
      console.log(events)
    })
})()